# Bound summation of successive square roots

Tags: summation, asymptotics

What is a tight upper bound for $f(n)$ where $f(n) = f(\sqrt{n}) + \frac{1}{n}$.  One can easily find the following upper bound $O(\lg \lg n)$, however I'm interested in a tight bound.

Regards.

Comment: Since $u^{1/2^i} \to 1$, I would say that the best upper bound you can get is $\infty$.

Comment: By $f(\sqrt{n})$ do you mean $f(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $f$ is defined on the integers and that your recurrence is really

$$
f(n) = f(\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor) + \frac{1}{n}.
$$

For a given $n \in \mathbb N$ let $m = \lfloor \lg \lg n \rfloor$, where $\lg = \log_2$.  It follows that

$$
2^{2^m} \leq n < 2^{2^{m+1}}. \tag{1}
$$

Define the integers $\{s_k\}_{k=0}^{m+1}$ by $s_{m+1} = n$ and

$$
s_k = \left\lfloor \sqrt{s_{k+1}} \right\rfloor, \qquad k=0,1,\ldots,m.
$$

From $(1)$ we see that $s_0 = 1$ and

$$
s_k \geq 2^{2^{k-1}}
$$

for all $k$, so upon unfolding the recurrence for $f$ we find that

$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &= f(1) + \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{s_k} \\
&\leq f(1) + \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 2^{-2^{k-1}} \\
&< f(1) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-2^k}.
\end{align}
$$

In particular, $f(n) = O(1)$.